# jQuery Rapid Class Switcher

Tags: jquery, class, hover, switch-statement

> http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/re73T/

Trying to make a class switcher that will do the following:

> 1. On Load - randomly select one of 10 classes to add to an element
> 2. While Hovering - Rapidly (every 0.4s) switch between 10 classes
> 3. On mouseOut - leave the current class active

I've tried several ways of doing this, none of which have worked.

> What do you think would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @FishBasketGordo don't worry it was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different implementation that works in your jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/b7A4a/.  This one also makes sure that the randomly generated class name is different than the previous one so the color actually changes every 400ms rather than skipping a change 1 out of 10 times because it generates the same color value that it just had.

```
// get unique random class that's different than what is currently being used
function getRandomClass(prior) {
    var r;
    do {
        r = "class" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
    } while (prior && prior.match(new RegExp("\\b" + r + "\\b")));
    return(r);
}

// initialize the current class
$(".element").addClass(getRandomClass());

// upon hover, start the timer, when leaving stop the timer
$(".element").hover(function() {
    var self = this;
    if (this.intervalTimer) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalTimer);
        this.intervalTimer = null;
    }
    this.intervalTimer = setInterval(function() {
        var c = self.className;
        self.className = c.replace(/\bclass\d+\b/, getRandomClass(c));
    }, 400);
}, function() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalTimer);
    this.intervalTimer = null;
});
```

Comment: Is there any way this can be packaged as a jquery function like `.switchclasses()`

Comment: @JamesKyle - in your jsFiddle implementation, you have to change "class" to "state" in another place that you missed: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nPVxb/80/.

Comment: No packaging is necessary.  In the code, change `".element"` to `".switcher"` and then just add `"switcher"` to any element you want to have this behavior.  If the `switcher` class is on the object in the original page HTML, then this code will just work with any object that has that class.  If you want to dynamically add the `switcher` class, then you'd have to change the code to use either `.live()` or `.on()` depending upon which version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: thank you!!! you can see it in use here: http://playground.thejameskyle.com/qwiqly/index.html

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/re73T/9/

```
// On Load
//     Randomly select 1 of 10 classes


function removeAllClasses() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
        $('.element').removeClass('class' + i);
    }
}

function setRandomClass() {
    var cls = "class"+Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1) + 1);
    $('.element').addClass(cls);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    removeAllClasses(); // just in case
    setRandomClass();
});

// While Hovering
//    every 0.4s 
//        switch to the next class out of ten
// I want it to leave the current class when you mouseout
var IS_HOVERING = false;
$('.element').hover(function() {
    IS_HOVERING = true;
}, function() {
    IS_HOVERING = false;
});

function onTimeout() {
    if (IS_HOVERING) {
        removeAllClasses();
        setRandomClass();
    }
    setTimeout(onTimeout, 400);
}

setTimeout(onTimeout, 400);
```

Comment: wow I didn't expect someone to actually do all that for me, thank you!!